# Dockerize Spring Boot applications: services don't connect to each other

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerize my Spring Boot application, made of multiple microservices (each a spring boot application) and a MongoDB database, running on different containers. The application runs fine locally, but on docker the microservices are not able to connect to each other.

I'll give an example with 3 services: rest api ms (Eureka Client), service discovery ms (Eureka Server), and MongoDB service.

Specifically for this example, the rest api ms tries to connect to `http://localhost:8761/eureka/` instead to `http://service-discovery:8761/eureka/` (below). To MongoDB it does connect but the db is empty when `MONGO_HOST = mongodb`, but when `MONGO-HOST = host.docker.internal` it works fine.

Logs:

```
INFO 1 --- [rest-ms] [}-mongodb:27017] [] org.mongodb.driver.cluster: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongodb:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=21, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=118400938}
```

```
INFO 1 --- [rest-ms] [main] [] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to http://localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to http://localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
```

application.properties of rest api ms:

```
# DB
spring.data.mongodb.host=${MONGO_HOST:localhost}
spring.data.mongodb.port=${MONGO_PORT:27017}
spring.data.mongodb.database=${MONGO_DB:mydb}

# server
server.port=8082
spring.application.name=rest-ms

eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=${EUREKA_PATH:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

# logger
logging.level.com.com1.restapi=DEBUG
logging.file.name=logs/restapi.log

# prometheus
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

# zipkin
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0
management.zipkin.tracing.endpoint=http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
```

dockerfile of rest api ms:

```
FROM openjdk:19-jdk-alpine

LABEL authors="author"

RUN addgroup -S rest-group && adduser -S rest-user -G rest-group

USER rest-user

WORKDIR /restapi

COPY ./target/restapi.jar .

EXPOSE 8082

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "restapi.jar"]
```

application.properties of service dicovery:

```
# server
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=service-discovery-ms

# discovery service
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

# logger
logging.level.com.com1.servicediscovery=DEBUG
logging.file.name=logs/serviceDiscoveryLog.log

# prometheus
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

# zipkin
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0
management.zipkin.tracing.endpoint=http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
```

dockerfile of service discovery:

```
FROM openjdk:19-jdk-alpine

LABEL authors="author"

RUN addgroup -S discovery-group && adduser -S discovery-user -G discovery-group

USER discovery-user

WORKDIR /discovery

COPY ./target/ServiceDiscovery.jar .

EXPOSE 8761

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "ServiceDiscovery.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  rest-ms:
    build: ./rest-ms
    image: rest-image
    container_name: rest-container
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      MONGO_HOST: mongodb
      MONGO_PORT: 27017
      MONGO_DB: mydb
      EUREKA_PATH: http://service-discovery:8761/eureka/
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - service-discovery

  service-discovery:
    build: ./ServiceDiscovery
    image: service-discovery-image
    hostname: service-discovery
    container_name: service-discovery-container
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
```

What i do know is that rest-ms does gets the environment variables and does set the properties accordingly, yet it tries to connect to the localhost instead.

Comment: MONGO_HOST=mongodb is empty because when you launch a container, it starts from scratch, so if you don't persist the data, it will be lost every time you run the container. You must make a volume if you want your database in the docker container.
MONGO-HOST=host.docker.internal works because you have a database on your host machine, so here you are connecting to your hsot machine's database, not your container's database.